# Twilio sms mysql insert

Tags: php, mysql, twilio

I'm trying to insert content from an sms from Twilio into mysql.  The response at the bottom comes back correctly, but the data is not being inserted into mysql. I'm not sure what I'm missing.  Any help?

```
<?php
header("content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";

$From = $_REQUEST['From'];
$To = $_REQUEST['To'];
$Body = $_REQUEST['Body'];

$host="host"; // Host name 
$username="user"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="database_name"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="table"; // Table name

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (From, To, Body) VALUES ('$From', '$To', '$Body')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<Response>
<Sms><?php echo $From ?> has messaged <?php echo $To ?> with the message of <?php echo    $Body ?></Sms>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"INSERT INTO $tbl_name (From, To, Body) VALUES ('$From', '$To', '$Body')";
```

You have following problmes here.

1. table name is `table`. table name can not be `table`. **`table` is a MySQL keyword**.
2. **`From` and `To` are keywords** in mysql.

Escape the keywords (with  `)  in this query to make it work. Like this

```
"INSERT INTO `$tbl_name` (`From`, `To`, `Body`) VALUES ('$From', '$To', '$Body')";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  With regard to problem #1 - the table name is actually 'sms', not table, so that shouldn't be an issue.  I changed the variables to 'sender' and 'dest' so I don't run into that issue again.  Still no luck...

Comment: I am doing almost same thing with twilio api. But I store more information

Comment: Shiplu - perhaps you can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just escape and your query will work. Also its better to store as many values as you can. I stored all with an extra timestamp.

Comment: Ok, got the query working, but Twilio is showing a parse error.  Any ideas on that?  Says line 2: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking the output of  `mysql_error()`. Both `FROM` and `TO` are [MySQL reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), which must be quoted in backticks to be used as column names.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `$tbl_name` (`From`, `To`, `Body`) VALUES ('$From', '$To', '$Body')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
   // Problem!
   echo mysql_error();
}
```

Beyond this, your script is vulnerable to SQL injection. At a minimum, you must call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on each of those values. Consider switching to an API supporting prepared statements, like PDO or MySQLi.

```
$From = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['From']);
$To = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['To']);
$Body = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Body']);
```

Comment: With regard to the security, I will add it after I confirm the script is inserting data correctly.  I checked the error and I'm not getting an error back, but the data is not in the table...